# selenium webdriver xpath generation

Tags: xpath, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I want to create an xpath for clicking on "run " (4th column) based on the first column value (xyz). the below xpath doesnt work. Can you suggest a better way of writing the xpath.

```
//table/tbody/tr/td[text()='xyz fix']/parent::tr/td[4]
```

```
<div id="main">
   <table class="FixedLayout" width="1000px">
      <tbody>
         <tr></tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="RowHeight">
               <a href="/TestPass/View/373">xyz</a>
            </td>
            <td>xyz fix</td>
            <td>1125</td>
            <td>
               <a href="/Instance/Create?suiteId=373">Run</a>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="RowHeight">
               <a href="/TestPass/View/372">abc</a>
            </td>
            <td>abc fix</td>
            <td>1125</td>
            <td>
               <a href="/Instance/Create?suiteId=372">Run</a>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why your one didn't work. Please clarify what it means "doesn't work". `NoSuchElementException`? `ElementNotVisibleException`? Wrong XPath? Not clicking the link or what?

Meanwhile, try the following XPaths (but the issue could be your Selenium code instead of XPath):

Here I assume you want to the `<a>` link instead of `<td>`, because you mentioned you want to click it.

Use XPath predicate:

```
//*[@id='main']//table/tobdy/tr[td[text()='xyz']]/td[4]/a
```

Use XPath predicate with attribute selector to avoid using index.

```
//*[@id='main']//table/tobdy/tr[td[text()='xyz']]//a[contains(@href, 'Instance/Create')]
```

Use `..` to get the parent

```
//*[@id='main']//table/tobdy/tr/td[text()='xyz']/../td[4]/a
```

Comment: I would go for your 2nd option, with `//*[@id='main']//table//tr[contains(td, 'xyz fix')]/td/a[contains(@href, 'Instance/Create')]`

Comment: Thanks paul and user1177636  for your help. The second option works well.

    //*[@id='main']//table//tr[contains(td, 'xyz fix')]/td/a[contains(@href, 'Instance/Create')]